# "files.defaultLanguage": "powershell" fails to set default lanaguage to PowerShell for Visual Studio Code on Mac 1.24.1

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I want to make #PowerShell the default language in Visual Studio Code on Mac 1.24.1 so that after I enter ⌘N I can immediately start typing PowerShell code and have all the parsing and completion and syntax highlighting work.

Under "User Settings" I did this:

```
{
    "files.defaultLanguage": "powershell"
}
```

I then exited and restarted Visual Studio Code.

I then tried ⌘N and typed $ps and pressed the tab key.  I got a tab.  No completion.  No highlighting.

What did I do wrong?

I'm a complete newb with Visual Studio Code so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code block:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.txt": "powershell"
 }
```

- Add it to your settings file in %appdata%\Code\User\settings.json
- Remenber to place that code block within the first top level indentation

*Edit: This works in PC. I am not sure in MAC environments, maybe you can leverage MAC extensions and so the same there.